# Open txt file through notepad using Qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to open a text file in notepad using Qt but it keeps giving me this message:

[image]

What I'm using is the following:
`QProcess::startDetached("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", { ":/notes.txt" });`

Comment: This `:/notes.txt` doesn't seem to be a valid file path.

Comment: This file is added to the resources and I'm using it without any problem in other parts of the program

Comment: Well, but `Notepad` is not a part of your program. It doesn't know anything about the resources you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Qt compiles resources added to a resource file into a binary format. Notepad (or any external tool) does not have access to the individual files that are part of it. If you want to provide access to the file to an external program, you'll have to either distribute your txt file alongside your application or write it to a temporary file on the fly before trying to open it.

After doing either of the two, you can then open your file with an external tool by passing the full path to `QProcess::startDetached` like it has been mentioned in [David Cornejo's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75298492/2865814)